# Why permission dialog disappear when application is open again?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I have added READ_PHONE_STATE permission in my project.

Scenario:
I am just opening my application and I get Permission alert **“Allow My Application to make and manage phone calls ?"**
Now I am moving my application in background and again opening by tap on My Application icon
Result: **“Allow My Application to make and manage phone calls ?"** Permission pop up get disappears.

Can any one tell why this behaviour?
Note: I am using launchMode="singleInstance" and when using launchMode="standard" all is working fine.

Sharing my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final Integer REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERMISSION = 0x1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    askForPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERMISSION);
}

public static void askForPermission(Activity context, String permission, Integer requestCode) {
    if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) && (context != null) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(permission) == false)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
    }
}}
```

Comment: add that code on onResume

Comment: not sure why the popup disapears but adding `askForPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERMISSION);`to onResume should fix the problem

Comment: If you have allow once a permission to your application then second time it don't show dialog until manually revoke permission because you have already given permission for that. And if you want to check every time then you need to add code in you onResume() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on singleTask behaviour

**If an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance.**

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#TaskLaunchModes

I was able to fix this issue by handling the code in

onNewIntent(Intent intent)

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    askForPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERMISSION);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final Integer REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERMISSION = 0x1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @override
    private void onResume(){
    askForPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_PERMISSION);
    }

    public static void askForPermission(Activity context, String permission, Integer requestCode) {
        if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) && (context != null) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(permission) == false)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` in `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
```

This will launch activity again and your code will work in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Use Runtime Permission like this:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
        Context context;
        Activity activity;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            context = this;
            activity = this;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            if (!checkPermission()) {
                OpenActivity();
            } else {
                if (checkPermission()) {
                    requestPermissionAndContinue();
                } else {
                    OpenActivity();
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean checkPermission() {
            return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }

        private void requestPermissionAndContinue() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("STORAGE permission is necessary to write event!!!");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivityANother.this, new String[]{READ_PHONE_STATE,
                            }, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    Log.e("", "permission denied, show dialog");
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{READ_PHONE_STATE
                    }, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

                }
            } else {
                OpenActivity();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

            if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (permissions.length > 0 && grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean flag = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag) {
                        OpenActivity();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }

                } else {
                    finish();
                }
            } else {
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }

        private void OpenActivity() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

and Add 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` in to menifist file.

Hope this Helps you